# C++ Reading text file, storing objects and printing out array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, pointers

I'm reading in an input file with tab delimited Firstname, Lastname and zipcode. There are 25 of them. I'm trying to read it in, store it into objects and print it out again.

Here's the code:

```
// Reading in from an input file 
ifstream inputFile("nameInput.txt");
string line;

for(int i = 0; i<25; i++){
    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        istringstream getInput(line);
        string tempFName, tempLName;
        int tempZip;

        getInput >> tempFName >> tempLName >> tempZip;

        // Creating new Person objects with the data
        persons[i] = new Person(tempFName, tempLName, tempZip);
    }
    inputFile.close();
    // Printing out String representation of the Person
    persons[i]->toString();
}
```

While it compiles, during run-time this is the error I get: 87023
Segmentation fault: 11

Please help!!

Comment: Show us the declaration of `persons`.

Comment: Sorry, here it is:  // array declaration
 Person* persons[25];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, you need only one loop. This will read a maximum of 25 lines:

```
int main()
{
    const int n_persons = 25;
    std::shared_ptr<Person> persons[n_persons];
    std::ifstream inputFile("nameInput.txt");
    std::string line;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_persons && std::getline(inputFile, line); ++i)
    {
        std::istringstream getInput(line);
        std::string tempFName, tempLName;
        int tempZip;

        if(getInput >> tempFName >> tempLName >> tempZip)
        {
            // Creating new Person objects with the data
            persons[i] = new Person(tempFName, tempLName, tempZip);

            // Printing out string representation of the Person
            persons[i]->toString();
        }
        else
            cout << "error on line #" << i + 1 << " occurred" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd perhaps add some checks after reading input to make sure that 25 persons were read. OP doesn't appear to be tracking the actual size of the array, so it sounds like 25 or bust. a #define N 25 would be useful in that case, to stem the copying of a magic number.

Comment: this work. thank you. I'm really new to C++. This was the first lab. I'll keep working at it.